# Manhua/webtoon where the main character runs a shop, has a healing power, and is called a zombie

Tags: story-identification, manga

There are beings with special powers that live among the humans, and fight and kill each other for their cores to grow stronger. The MC is a human that has a healing power, even though it's impossible for a human to have powers.

It starts with the MC getting caught up in a fight with these beings and being "killed". Then, when a human organization that hides the beings and works to kill them to protect humans starts to clean the mass from their fight, they find his "body" and he comes back to life.